# How to show subdirectories using SFTP ls command

Tags: bash, scripting, sftp

I'm trying to get subdirectories list in a folder

`echo "ls -1 /path/to/folder/*/" | sftp -i /path/to/key user@host | grep -v 'sftp>'`

If there is more than one subdirectory I get list of subdirectories:

```
/path/to/folder/subdirectory1/
/path/to/folder/subdirectory2/
```

If there is only one subdirectory I get nothing.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Note: using SSH is not allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If there is only one subdirectory I get nothing.

You should only *get nothing* if the *only one subdirectory* is empty, because `ls` if given a single directory argument lists its contents. With the normal `ls` we could solve this problem simply by means of the option `-d`, but unfortunately `sftp`'s `ls` doesn't have that option. The only way coming to my mind is to filter the desired directories from a long listing:

```
echo "ls -l /path/to/folder" | sftp -i /path/to/key user@host | awk '/^d/{print "/path/to/folder/"$NF}'
```

Comment: it's not problem to get list of subdirectories even though they are all empty.
But if there is the only subdirectory in the folder it is not possible

Comment: I described wherefrom the difference comes. Did you try my suggestion, and do you still think _it is not possible_?

Comment: it works perfectly. Thank you for your advice!

One more question - is it possible to append end-of-line `\n` to the end of the string? Something like `printf '%s\n'` ?

Comment: Hm - the shown `awk` `print` command already does append a `\n`; but of course if you want another one, you can write `print "/path/to/folder/"$NF"\n"`.